# Access request.format from Rails ApplicationController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a before_action filter in my ApplicationController. If the format of the request is 'application/json', I'd like to put an additional check requiring an API key. How do I check the request.format from the application controller? The line in question is:

```
  before_action :check_api_access, if: request.format.json?
```

The error I'm getting is

> undefined local variable or method `request' for ApplicationController:Class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a lambda:

```
before_action :check_api_access, if: -> { request.format.json? }
```